# Why is $U(10)\not\approx U(12)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to understand this example on isomorphism but failing to do so. I know that if two groups have a differing number of elements of each order they are not isomorphic. I assume this is what they are saying. Particularly, how is it that $\phi(3)\phi(3)$ and $\phi(1)\phi(1)$ both equal 1?

[image]

Comment: What does $U$ stand for here?

Comment: Also, your question is "Why is $U(12)\approx U(12)$", but the example you posted shows just the opposite...

Comment: My mistake in typing Mathjax, sorry.

Comment: $U(n)$ is multiplication mod n.

Comment: @Akyidrian Thanks to the answer by Zev Chonoles I finally understand your question and $U(n)$ is multiplication mod n restricted to coprimes of n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
U(10)&=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}:x\text{ is a unit}\}=\{1+10\mathbb{Z},\;3+10\mathbb{Z},\;7+10\mathbb{Z},\;9+10\mathbb{Z}\}\\
U(12)&=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}:x\text{ is a unit}\}=\{1+12\mathbb{Z},\;5+12\mathbb{Z},\;7+12\mathbb{Z},\;11+12\mathbb{Z}\}\\
\end{align*}$$
Both $U(10)$ and $U(12)$ are groups with $4$ elements.

(For convenience, we often drop the coset notation, but remember that it's still there implicitly.)

As is explained in the excerpt, we have $x^2=1$ for every $x\in U(12)$. That is,
$$\left.\begin{align*}
(1+12\mathbb{Z})^2&=1+12\mathbb{Z}\\
(5+12\mathbb{Z})^2&=25+12\mathbb{Z}\\
(7+12\mathbb{Z})^2&=49+12\mathbb{Z}\\
(11+12\mathbb{Z})^2&=121+12\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}\right\}\text{ all equal }1+12\mathbb{Z}$$
(In other words, $25\equiv 1\bmod 12$, and $49\equiv 1\bmod 12$, and $121\equiv 1\bmod 12$.)

We suppose, **for the sake of contradiction**, that $\phi:U(10)\to U(12)$ is a function that is a group isomorphism. In particular, for **any** input $a\in U(10)$, the output $\phi(a)$ is an element of $U(12)$, and (as observed) therefore must have the property that $\phi(a)^2=1$.

But since
$$\begin{align*}
\phi(9+10\mathbb{Z})=\phi\biggl((3+10\mathbb{Z})^2\biggr)=\phi(3+10\mathbb{Z})^2=1+12\mathbb{Z}\\
\phi(1+10\mathbb{Z})=\phi\biggl((1+10\mathbb{Z})^2\biggr)=\phi(1+10\mathbb{Z})^2=1+12\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{align*}$$
(No matter **what** the value of $\phi(3+10\mathbb{Z})$ is! all we need to know is that it's an element of $U(12)$!) we see that $\phi$ is not injective, and therefore cannot be a group isomorphism as was assumed.

Comment: Was 3 chosen arbitrarily from $U(10)$ when used with the homomorphism property? Could the same argument be applied to the other elements of $U(10)$? Is $x^2=1$ also just a property of the question? I still find it confusing :(

Comment: @Akyidrian: $9$ wasn't chosen arbitrarily. The proof works by observing that the perfect squares in $U(10)$ are $1^2=1$, $3^2=9$, $7^2=9$, and $9^2=1$. So only 1 and 9 are perfect squares. You want to choose a perfect square so you can assert $\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)^2=1$ for distinct $a^2$.

Answer (score 4):

As written explicitly, in $U(12)$ we have $g^2=1$ for every element $g$. Hence, $\phi(3)^2=\phi(1)^2=1$.

However, what you wrote about differing numbers of elements of the same order is indeed a simpler way to think of it. In $U(10)$ there are elements of order $4$, and in $U(12)$ there are no such elements. Consequently, the two groups cannot be isomorphic to one another.